# how to extract .mobi file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-filesystem

As we know .mobi doesn't support javascript so i want to create a javascript wrapper for .mobi file where i can extract them and apply javascript event.

```
<div id="js-container">

Extracted html from .mobi file

</div>
```

Comment: On the format http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/MOBI. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications , File API http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/ .

Comment: but i couldn't find the way where to start. like there are zip.js and rar.js to extract zip and rar files respectively

Comment: If can create a jsfiddle , post link to `.mobi` file , can try pieces at jsfiddle ?

Comment: how can i add .mobi file in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4m6Af/